# std::shared_ptr with std containers

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, set, shared-ptr

I have a container of `shared_ptr`s and I hand these objects off to a windows API and I get a callback later with the raw ptr. I want to locate the right `shared_ptr` after the fact. Can this be done with shared_ptr cleanly? (without using `shared_from_this()`).

very basic example:

```
class CFoo
{
};
typedef std::shared_ptr<CFoo> CFooPtr;
typedef std::set<CFooPtr> CFooSet;

extern CFooSet m_gSet;
void SomeWindowsCallBack(CFoo* pRawPtr)
{
  m_gSet.erase(pRawPtr);
}
```

I know that this can be done with `intrusive_ptr` very easily but I am curious if there is a way with `shared_ptr`. Aka I am looking for the container to accept the RawPtr and the shared_ptr for locating the `shared_ptr` item. The issue is that I can't implicitly cast the `CFoo*` into the shared_ptr (for reasons I do understand).

I was thinking I could do

`m_gSet.erase(shared_ptr<CFoo>(pRawPtr, _do_not_delete_deleter))`

but I have not tried that yet and it seems dangerous/ugly. Is there another way or am I basically looking for `intrusive_ptr`? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not the obvious way? Iterate through the container, and

```
if(iterator->get() == rawPointer)
   container.erase(iterator)
```

Edit: To utilize O(logN) lookup you can do what you want (that is, create a shared_ptr with no_op deleter). It may be ugly, but it's not dangerous

Comment: yes I could do that but containers like set and map allow O(LogN) look up and that method would place me back to O(N). I was hoping to not lose the O(LogN) look up.

Comment: so would you take that option over using intrusive_ptr or would you consider the circumstance as a argument for going with intrusive_ptr in the first place? (the cast to shared_ptr<no_delete_deleter> would perform some allocations in the background)

Comment: @BabelFish: Fortunately, the deleter is not a template argument of the shared pointer! So no cast is required

Comment: what I meant was that by converting the ptr into a shared_ptr would result in an allocation in the background (the allocation for the reference info)). sorry for the confusion